# Handlers with listBox on mobile

Tags: google-apps-script

Are client and server handlers assigned to a listBox, that work on the desktop, suppose to function on mobile browsers in the same way?

I tried out [this example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwpo1YtexOD873ioYU0xXnClL-asiBM8UBazfAoRRRaM5gDqga2/exec) by Serge on the Desktop (worked fine) and on my mobile browser (did not fire).

[My own example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwnY60555lBPe0jWdcFWG3DHIz-3ZO98uY7Xz2fh6Sqz2EUVIH6/exec) is the same way, neither the client or server handler executes on the mobile side.

Comment: [Code](https://script.google.com/d/1wYZ_Dc1QXoFdwfL8dLFYYmyzTlJBHhT5A4ZiguBH3rN1z7rJoljDZ-Ue/edit)

Comment: Are you using an Android device or an Apple?  I use Android default browser without any issue and/or chrome or Firefox for Android too.

Comment: Tried both examples on Android 2.3 (default browser and Miren browser), waiting for feedback on iPhone.

Comment: in your example (on android 4.1) the first listbox works normally but the second appears empty until I repeat action on the first... then works normally (hoping what I say is understandable ;-)

Comment: The second will start out empty, then populate depending on which item is clicked in the first.  Couldn't get mine to work on iPhone 4, yours worked like half the time.  I'll try the button widget instead.  Wondering if this is more of a GWT issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Issue 1092](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1092) could be relevant. You'll require two taps on iPhone and Android.